# How to benefit Data augmentation when it yields to different classes

Tags: keras, image-classification, data-augmentation

I'm trying to classify rooftop sky images orientations, whether it is horizontal or vertical. Knowing that the most obvious feature here is known: orientation. I can simply augment each class by rotating it 90° so it belongs to the other class. It is like dynamic augmentation to different classes.

Using keras image classification capabilities, obviously defeats the purpose:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        zoom_range=0.2, # randomly zoom into images
#       rotation_range=90,  # mistaken the model
        horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images
```

I am using keras for classification but open to other libraries, and techniques other than deep learning.

Comment: So, basically, you can use any other augmentation provided in keras ImageDataGenerator instead of rotation? 

You could use rotation_range with a small value, like up to 10 degrees ...

Comment: Other data augmentation techniques provided in ImageDataGenerator should not result in a class change.

Comment: that's what I'm emphasizing. I want to augment data in an aware way to other classes. In my case, augmenting each class (horizontal and vertical) by rotation of 90° to the other opposite labeled class. how could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You could rotate images manually (without using `ImageDataGenerator`) and save it to disk.
That way you would know which images you have rotated - so you would know which images have changed the class.

After it, when using `ImageDataGenerator`, you need to set `rotation_range` to small value in order to be sure that it won't change the classes of images.

Examples how to rotate image manually can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43864937/5997950